# How to edit SQL records using Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got like 2000 rows of data, when I do select statement I can narrow my query but I cant change any value, as I have to change 50 columns, I dont want to use Update Command as then because values I have to update for each row is unique.

Anyone knows any easier way of selecting data using select command and then edit it.

**EDIT**

I just went to SQL Management studio, clicked on DB I am working on then find the table, I right clicked on it and then it says "Select top 1000 rows" so Now I can see the query and the data, I added  "Where" into query and got what I wanted, but I cant modify the table rows below :S

**Edit 2 **

Or I can develop a Utility that will take Table Name , Column Name and its New value and simply updates it :)

Comment: Please show us your query, sample data, and desired output.

Comment: What are you using to edit the data?  SSMS?

Comment: I would love to if it wasn't private data of clients :(

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg Sample obfuscated data is fine. The query engine doesn't know the difference. See your username? Same kinda thing ;)

Comment: Your edit seems to indicate you want to be able to use a UI to filter data in a table, then manually edit individual records of data.  If so, you could use a tool like DBVisualizer, or TOAD for SQL Server - both these let you do that in a UI without writing any SQL.  If you're trying to edit individual records of data programmatically, you should learn the basics of T-SQL.

Comment: How will your "utility" know which row(s) to update? And in writing this utility, won't you have to code the `UPDATE` statements behind it?

Comment: it wont gonna save me a lot of effort other then changing values in text boxes then changing them in a SQL query. BUT I look into DML commands now and see if I could find any easier way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You modify data using an `UPDATE` statement (with a `WHERE` clause) in a query window. While Management Studio has a feature called "Edit Top n Rows" that doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it - there are several behavioral bugs that are still unresolved even in the SQL Server 2012 version, and it can also place unnecessary and prohibitive locks on the underlying table.

I know it's not the answer you want to hear, but please become comfortable with proper DML commands. The documentation for `UPDATE` is found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=sql.100).aspx

The long and short of it, IMHO: If you can identify the rows you want to update by using a `SELECT` with a `WHERE` clause, you can also write an `UPDATE` query using the same `WHERE` clause.

Comment: As a programmer, I would tend to agree.  However, there is a time and place for using the edit option when you have data that is not actively being used by an application and just need to massage or prepare it.

Comment: @mellamokb I disagree. Becoming comfortable with DML rather than relying on UIs leads to better long-term skills, more consistency, and enables you to worry only about the statement you are writing and not how the UI you're using is implemented (and whether your edits will fall into any of the unresolved bugs).

Comment: so I must have to execute 50 SQL commands for updating 50 rows, doesn't sounds alright

Comment: @AaronBertrand: You're not being practical... I whip out the edit Top n rows once in awhile if it happens to be a faster method to do an update than writing DML - and I've written a LOT of DML.  They are both tools for accomplishing a business goal, and have their relevant places.

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg you can use a [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.100).aspx) rather than writing 50 different commands. Please learn a little about `UPDATE` before summarily rejecting it. Use the UI as a crutch if you want; I'm trying to show you how to become a better programmer rather than a lazier one. Just because it's easier in the beginning doesn't make it better.

Comment: @mellamokb actually I think I am being practical. I'd rather have people learn to fish properly than use a buggy fishing pole that requires gas to run and is sometimes more convenient but usually far less convenient than a stick with a line hanging from it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Sounds good :)  I guess we'll respectfully disagree.

Comment: @mellamokb yes, I realize not everyone wants to learn how to fish, and not everyone is willing to teach them how to fish. I lean toward teaching to fish and hope they want to learn. This doesn't always work out, but my first instinct is never the quick, potentially problematic "solution."

Answer (score 5):

In SSMS - in the same place you saw "Select top 1000 rows", there should be another option "Open table" or "Edit top 200 Rows" (by default).

If you did that on a table, then pressed the following button:

[image]

You should then by able to paste in your select statement you've already written instead of what is there, press the execute button (Red exclamation mark button). The grid that appears *is* editable.

In general I'd be inclined to agree with @AaronBertrand though, it's better to learn the syntax to `Update` statements yourself.

Comment: Yup already seen that, but again I will have to execute 50 commands :(

Comment: @fdgfdgsdfg Why would you have to execute 50 commands? This gives you the results in an editable grid, you can edit all 50 columns if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Microsoft Access, you can create a linked table to your sql server database and edit it by opening the table and modifying the relevant rows.  You can create a query in Microsoft Access as well limiting the rows you want to return, and then you can inline edit the columns you'd like to change in the result set.

See for example [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1480/configure-microsoft-access-linked-tables-with-a-sql-server-database/) how to create a linked table to SQL Server.